# Spring Boot Jar file start by terminal using nohup

Tags: java, linux, spring

Spring has [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html) documentation for running an executable spring boot jar.

However, I ran this jar from terminal using the **nohup** linux command, and worked fine.

The question is: Using nohup or using init.d service, will have the same result for the application? Or using the init.d is the correct way always?

Answer (score 3):

They do different things. `nohup` runs a command, and ignores the HANGUP (HUP) signal. `init.d` is for running a command automatically at server start-up (and shutting commands down orderly on shutdown). If you want your spring boot application to run automatically after the system restarts, put it in `init.d` - if you want to manually start it after every reboot you can use `nohup`.

Answer (score 1):

`nohup` runs the command in a way that will be immune to hangups, which could cause problems. A lot of programs are designed to re-read their configuration files, restart, or do other things when they receive HUP signals (most services/daemons restart or re-read configs). Unless you specifically want to ignore HUP signals, using `nohup` isn't the best solution.

You can use `&` after the command in order to run it in the background, and if you want to avoid output to the terminal, you can send the output to /dev/null:

```
mycommand > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

The `2>&1` will send stderr to stdout, so it goes to /dev/null.